# Unconsistent quoting behaviour javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, variables, assign, quoting

I'm having some issues with getting consistent quoting inside my Javascript objects. For consistency I want to have all keys quoted but it's not working as expected once I use variables as keys.

When I create an entire object and push it to an array like this:

```
users.push({
    "username": username, 
    "userid": userId, 
    "memberof":membershipArr, 
    "sessions":{
        [sessionId]:[ws]
    }
});
```

The actual sessionId "key" is quoted with single quotes automatically, but when I retrieve an object and add new "child"objects to the session "value holder" they're not quoted. This is the code I'm using for that.

```
userobj.sessions[sessionId] = [ws];
```

This is how the object looks:

```
{
    username: 'DonaldDuck',
    userid: '1',
    memberof: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    sessions: 
    { 
     '3qti7jkhkjhkjhkjh4': [ [Object] ],
      j53bnmbmms7689ptlc4: [ [Object], [Object] ],
      bnbmnbnmb2nme2m2jk2: [ [Object] ] 
    } 
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong/in a bad way but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Whether a key is quoted or not matters little *in an object literal* (aside from stuff like keys with dashes). `{a: 1}` would produce the exact same object as `{"a": 1}` Once initialised, the object representation is completely independent from that - for both objects the `a` key would be the same. When that representation is being printed, how it's shown is implementation dependent. In this case, it appears `3qti7jkhkjhkjhkjh4` is being wrapped because it starts with a number which is not a normally valid way to have that key in an object literal.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried some more times, and you're correct. When the object is first assigned and starts with a number, it's being quoted. Would never have thought that. I know that the difference is very little, but I think it would "be best" to have it all either quoted, or not quoted. Is this possible or do I have to live with that the object keys will be different depending on it's value?

Comment: Unless you can override the way this value is being printed (I don't know if it's possible, but it might) - then, no it's not possible to change that. With a little caveat - if you have a plain JS object where the values are only primitives or arrays or objects, then you can turn it to JSON via `JSON.stringify` - in JSON all keys are always quoted. Printing that string will always be consistent. You can pretty print if you do `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)` - the last parameter causes the string to be properly indented.

Comment: Alright, I tried JSON stringifying my objects but since it contains websocket-objects which have circular references it doesn't work. So I'll have to live with the quoting differences. Thanks a lot for your help!